# RewriteRule : remove WWW on subdomain when HTTPS

Tags: mod-rewrite, removeall

Hi everybody (and sorry for my poor english).

For now, if someone write this, I have :

exemple.com -> https://www.exemple.com (OK)

subdomain1.exemple.com -> https://subdomain1.exemple.com (OK)

www.subdomain1.exemple.com -> https://subdomain1.exemple.com (OK)

https://exemple.com/blabla.htm -> https://www.exemple.com/blabla.htm (OK)

BUT if someone write directly:

https://www.subdomain1.exemple.com, there is not change and I have an error (connexion not secure because my SLL certificat is only for exemple.com and *.exemple.com).

So I would like remove www  like this :

https://www.subdomain1.exemple.com/blabla.htm -> https://subdomain1.exemple.com/blabla.htm
(where subdomain1 is not definite because it's a wildcard domain)

I hope it's clear for you and you can help me. Thanks very much !

Comment: Even if you have a rule to redirect from `www.sub.domain.com` to `sub.domain.com` on https version, the first connection to `www` version would still get that warning.

Comment: Hi. That's what I feared... Never mind. Thank you for your prompt response